# RoR - JS/Turbolink won't execute in prod

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In dev, I am able to get all my javascripts to execute on page load with the following format:

```
ready = ->
    #js code here....
    alert("THIS IS SOME GREAT JS CODE");

$(document).ready ready
$(document).on "page:load", ready
```

But when I go to prod, I get this error when I navigate to a new page:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Refreshing resolves the issue which makes me think js.

I have tried setting `config.serve_static_assets` to `true` but that didn't seem to help. Plus, It looks like Apache is supposed serve the static assets?

I've also tried running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` but that also had no affect.

**What else can I do to get my JS to run in prod on page load?**

EDIT:

I've narrowed it down to this section (in config/environments/development.rb):

```
# Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
config.assets.compile = true
# Generate digests for assets URLs.
config.assets.digest = true
```

EDIT 2:

I noticed in the logs that unless a refresh is done, the server doesn't get the assets:

Request 1:

```
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:26.996267 #16820]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 192.168.0.10 at 2015-01-23 15:56:26 -0500
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.038912 #16820]  INFO -- : Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.042287 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_search_bar.html.slim (1.2ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.295263 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered visitors/index.html.slim within layouts/application (254.3ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.301084 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_top_nav_links.html.slim (1.2ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.302838 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_top_nav.html.slim (4.3ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.303462 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.slim (0.1ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.304302 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.slim (0.5ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.304452 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_custom_menu.html.slim (0.7ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.305074 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.slim (0.4ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:27.305686 #16820]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 266ms (Views: 54.1ms | ActiveRecord: 211.0ms)
```

Request 2:

```
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.444562 #16820]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 192.168.0.10 at 2015-01-23 15:56:37 -0500
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.485694 #16820]  INFO -- : Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.490369 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_search_bar.html.slim (1.4ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.743531 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered visitors/index.html.slim within layouts/application (254.7ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.745333 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_top_nav_links.html.slim (0.3ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.745334 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_top_nav.html.slim (0.7ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.745606 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_messages.html.slim (0.1ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.747027 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.slim (0.4ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.747204 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_custom_menu.html.slim (0.6ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.747876 #16820]  INFO -- :   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.slim (0.4ms)
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.748460 #16820]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 262ms (Views: 49.1ms | ActiveRecord: 210.8ms)
# THESE LINES HERE
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:37.987461 #16820]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/bootstrap.css.map" for 192.168.0.10 at 2015-01-23 15:56:37 -0500
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:38.065490 #17240]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" for 192.168.0.10 at 2015-01-23 15:56:38 -0500
I, [2015-01-23T15:56:38.066049 #16820]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/sprites.png" for 192.168.0.10 at 2015-01-23 15:56:38 -0500
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML source of the page from production? Compared to dev?

Comment: `turbolinks` doesn't load things in the head after the initial page load. Are you adding things to the head of your html?

Comment: No, to the application.js file (and the pages .js). I can either get the JS to work OR the images to load, but not both.

Comment: Now its mostly working, its just trying to find assets without the compiled text behind it (its looking for glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf instead of glyphicons-halflings-regular-jhklaw3kuhsadfkjfhawu4kehr.ttf).